# Flex box column not equal width with flex: 1

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Hi I am trying to make flex columns equal width but it doesn't seem to be working with `flex: 1`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.17/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center content-center mt-20 lg:mt-0 min-h-85 fade fadeout">

  <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-red-100">
    <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-red-200">
      <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1</h4>
      <p>Box 1 Flexbox 00000000</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-blue-100">
    <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-blue-200">
      <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2</h4>
      <p>Box 2 Flexbox 0</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="flex flex-col w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-green-100">
    <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-green-200">
      <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 3</h4>
      <p>Box 4 Flexbox 000</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

I want it to be the size of the flex col with the widest content.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I come to

If an element has flex: 1 , this means the size of all of the other elements will have the same width as their content, but the element with flex: 1 will have the remaining full space given to it.

### Soln

You can use `grid grid-cols-{n}` to equally distribute a row into `n` number of columns . I had shared the code below .

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.17/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <section class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center items-center content-center mt-20 lg:mt-0 min-h-85 fade fadeout">

      <div class="grid grid-cols-3 w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-red-100">
        <div class="bg-red-100"></div>
        <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-red-200 text-center">
          <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 1</h4>
          <p>Box 1 Flexbox 00000000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-red-100"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid grid-cols-3 w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-blue-100">
      <div class="bg-blue-100"></div>
        <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-blue-200 text-center">
          <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 2</h4>
          <p>Box 2 Flexbox 0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-blue-100"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="grid grid-cols-3 w-full md:w-1/3 max-w-md items-center bg-green-100">
      <div class="bg-green-100"></div>
        <div class="py-12 flex-1 bg-green-200 text-center">
          <h4 class="font-semibold tracking-widest text-xs">Box 3</h4>
          <p>Box 4 Flexbox 000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bg-green-100"></div>
      </div>

    </section>
```

For more info refer the docs [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/grid-column)

Answer (score 0):

The `flex: 1` isn't applied to flex item siblings.

It's applied to the children of those siblings (i.e., cousins).

Therefore, there's no association between the items with `flex: 1`, and there's no reason for them to be equal length.

Comment: How would I go about making them equal width?

Comment: Make them siblings or use Grid.

Comment: Trying to straw away from grid - could you give me an example of how to keep the same layout and make them siblings?

Comment: You would have to restructure your HTML. Get rid of the second level divs in each section. So the `h4`s and `p`s are the children of the top level div. Then they're all siblings and `flex: 1` could work as you want.